# How to clear all validators of single field from Zend Form?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

```
$form->fieldName->clearValidators();
```

I used `clearValidators()` to clear all validators of a single field of my zend form, and I wanted to clear validators when my action performs. But it doesn't work. Can anybody help?

Comment: I think you should use getElement() or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   $form->fieldName->setValidators(array());
```